# ORA-01720: grant option does not exist for XXX.VW_XXX while creating view in Oracle DB

Tags: sql, oracle, view, sql-grant

I am trying to update a view in oracle db but when i run the command it gives the following error. I don't change the declaration of the view, i am just running the same command that runs when the view is first created.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FORCE VIEW XXX.VW_XXX ... select * from aaa.VW_AA
```

> ORA-01720: grant option does not exist for aaa.VW_AA

But when i run the exact same command only changing the view name to a non-existing view name it runs successfully.

What might be causing this error and how can i solve it?

Comment: So, in your example is it user XXX running the CREATE OR REPLACE FORCE VIEW? Or a different user? Because I know what causes ORA-01720, at least in normal scenarios. But I'm having trouble understanding exactly what you're trying to do here. It would be helpful if you posted a simple step-by-step guide to reproducing this scenario, including the creation of the original view, whatever grants are involved, etc

Comment: I corrected the question with the right error.

Comment: Hmmm, I still don't see how that would give you ORA-01720. Yes if XXX is trying to grant privileges on their view to user DEF but not just from creating the view. There must be some other detail you're omitting.

Comment: check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36551639/oracle-error-when-creating-view-ora-01720) out. Btw, have you considered using `grant .... with grant option` anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem.

In the original view there were INSERT and DELETE grants to other users but aaa didn't have the grants INSERT and DELETE to tables it was using.